# Sorting DataFrame within rows and getting the ranking

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following PySpark DataFrame :

```
+----+----------+----------+----------+
|  id|         a|         b|         c|
+----+----------+----------+----------+
|2346|2017-05-26|      null|2016-12-18|
|5678|2013-05-07|2018-05-12|      null|
+----+----------+----------+----------+
```

My ideal output is :

```
+----+---+---+---+
|id  |a  |b  |c  |
+----+---+---+---+
|2346|2  |0  |1  |
|5678|1  |2  |0  |
+----+---+---+---+
```

Ie the more recent the date within the row, the higher the score

I have looked at similar posts suggesting to use window function. The problem is that I need to order my values within the row, not the column.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the values in each row into an array and use [`pyspark.sql.functions.sort_array()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.sort_array) to sort it.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
cols = ["a", "b", "c"]
df = df.select("*", f.sort_array(f.array([f.col(c) for c in cols])).alias("sorted"))
df.show(truncate=False)
#+----+----------+----------+----------+------------------------------+
#|id  |a         |b         |c         |sorted                        |
#+----+----------+----------+----------+------------------------------+
#|2346|2017-05-26|null      |2016-12-18|[null, 2016-12-18, 2017-05-26]|
#|5678|2013-05-07|2018-05-12|null      |[null, 2013-05-07, 2018-05-12]|
#+----+----------+----------+----------+------------------------------+
```

Now you can use a combination of [`pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce) and [`pyspark.sql.functions.when()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) to loop over each of the columns in `cols` and find the corresponding index in the sorted array.

```python
df = df.select(
    "id",
    *[
        f.coalesce(
            *[
                f.when(
                    f.col("sorted").getItem(i) == f.col(c),
                    f.lit(i)
                ) 
                for i in range(len(cols))
            ]
        ).alias(c) 
        for c in cols
    ]
)
df.show(truncate=False)
#+----+---+----+----+
#|id  |a  |b   |c   |
#+----+---+----+----+
#|2346|2  |null|1   |
#|5678|1  |2   |null|
#+----+---+----+----+
```

Finally fill the `null` values with 0:

```python
df = df.na.fill(0)
df.show(truncate=False)
#+----+---+---+---+
#|id  |a  |b  |c  |
#+----+---+---+---+
#|2346|2  |0  |1  |
#|5678|1  |2  |0  |
#+----+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thank you. However I encounter a different result before filling the dataframe's null values with 0. The null values are taken into account for the ranking, therefore the result is not right. For instance, for the first row, I get the following ranking of columns a, b and c : 3, null, 2

Comment: What version of pyspark? Are you sure the `null`s are actually missing values and not the string `"null"`? This shouldn't happen but a quick fix would be to just subtract 1- ie make it `f.lit(i-1)` - but I suspect something else is happening here

Comment: I checked again and it appears that instead of null values, I have None values. in the input dataframe which I built from another source dataframe. When an id don't have a value for a column in the source dataframe, I get None values in my input dataframe. But thanks to your quick fix, I managed to handle this little problem.

Comment: It also appears that when you have two similar dates, these dates are ranked at the same number but the next date (the later) is ranked at rank 3 instead of rank 2. Instead of the sequence 1, 1, 2, we obtain the sequence 1, 1, 3

Comment: @johndoe43567 yes that is how this would work for ties. If you have different requirements, please [edit] your question or ask a new one with the updated problem.

Comment: Yes I understand. Thank you for your advice.